# Declaring a MANY_MANY relation with a classifier in yii

Tags: php, database, yii

Let's say I have the following database structure:

[image: database schema]
I have a `Classifier` table which contains a list of classifier types like "Eye color", "Hair color", "Shoe size", etc. It is linked to the `Property` table which has lists of properties that correspond to the classifier. For example, it could have `black`, `brown`, `white` and `red` for hair type and `US 8`, `US 9`, and `US 10` for shoe size. The `Person` table is linked to the `Property` table in a MANY_MANY fashion.

When this structure is declared in yii like so

`'properties'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Property', 'Xref(Person_id, Property_id)')`

I can do something like this:

```
 foreach ($person->properties as $property) {
     echo ($property->classifier->name.': '.$property->name);
 }
```

But what I am looking for is to address all properties separately, like `$person->hairColor` or `$person->shoeSize`.

Sure, I could declare multiple MANY_MANY relations with a condition (only on Classifier_id equal to some value). But for that I need to know all Classifier ids beforehand - not flexible at all.

But is there a way do declare this relation in yii so that it automatically parses the classifier? So that when I add a new row to the `Classifier` table, say, `build` and values like `slim` or `athletic`, I can just use `$person->build` without declaring a new relation?

Not only that, I'd like to use these in `CDbCriteria`, like so `$my_criteria->compare('build.name', 'slim')` as opposed to both comparing `Classifier_id` with what corresponds to `build` and `Property` with `'slim'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic `__get()` for that:

In your Person model (untested code sorry):

```
public function __get($prop)
{
    if ($this->properties->hasAttribute($prop))
    {
        return $this->property->$prop;
    }

    return null;
    // or maybe better
    return parent::__get($prop);
}
```

Be arware that overriding CActiveRecords __get() might be a problem and is not recommended. You should check that.

Comment: Thank you, that's a start. However, this would probably not work when used with CDbCriteria. I'll update the question.